# Proving $\lim_{r\to\infty} f(r,\theta)=l$ $\rightarrow$ $\lim_{(x,y)\to(\infty,\infty)} f(x,y)=l$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Would this method for proving
$\lim_{r\to\infty} f(r,\theta)=l$ $\rightarrow$ $\lim_{(x,y)\to(\infty,\infty)} f(x,y)=l$ be correct?

where $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ and $l$ finite and $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Using the $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ definition of the 2 limits:

(A) $\forall\epsilon>0$ there exists $N(\epsilon)\in \mathbb{R}$ such that

1. $x,y>N$
2. then $|f(x,y)-l|<\epsilon$

(B) $\forall\epsilon>0$ there exists $N_2(\epsilon)\in \mathbb{R}$

a.  $r>N_2$

b. then $|f(r,\theta)-l|<\epsilon$

Now, (B) holds therefore $\forall\epsilon>0$ there exists $N_2(\epsilon)\in \mathbb{R}$  such that $|f(r,\theta)-l|<\epsilon$ whenever $r>N_2$.

Since $\{f(x,y)|x,y>N_2\}\subset \{f(r,\theta)|r>N_2\}$ since $x,y>N_2$ implies $r>N_2\sqrt{2}$, therefore $|f(x,y)-l|<\epsilon$ whenever $x,y>N_2$
and hence (B)$\rightarrow$(A)

Comment: It is unclear what $(x,y)\to(\infty,\infty)$ means.  It should rather be $\|(x,y)\|\to\infty$, or $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\to\infty$, or something equivalent.   In that case, since $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r$, there is little to show but that the 2 statements are identical in meaning.

Comment: You might need the limit to go uniformly in $\theta$ to $l$ with $\lim_{r \to \infty} f(r,\theta)$ in order for the implication to be if and only if.

Comment: Based on your work, you are trying to prove an incorrect statement, because for the first quantity you are requiring only that the limit exists as $x$ and $y$ simultaneously go to $+\infty$.  Here is an example:  Try your reasoning on $f(x,y)=e^{-x-y}$.

Comment: @nayrb: I would presume it is automatically uniform in $\theta$, because $\lim\limits_{r\to\infty}f(r,\theta)=l$ would mean for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that $r>N$ implies $|f(r,\theta)-l|<\varepsilon$.  There is no dependence on $\theta$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer If we let the definition of the first limit be what's stated in (A), Can we prove (A)$\iff$(B)?

Comment: @Dosomemaths: No, please see my second comment.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Yes. But we still have (B) $\rightarrow$ (A). Is that correct?

Comment: As Jonas mentioned above, the only issue here is what you mean by $(x,y) \to (\infty, \infty)$. Presumably you mean $\|(x,y)\| \to \infty$.

Comment: @Dosomemaths:  Yes, because $x>N$ and $y>N$ implies $r>N$. (In fact it implies $r>\sqrt2N$, but the extra factor doesn't matter.)

Comment: I edited the question. Thanks~ :)

Comment: @JonasMeyer Would my prove be correct then?

Comment: @Dosomemaths: Yes I think so, in case $l$ is finite.